# How can I pass an array to a function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, function, methods

I have a function that save elements in an array onclick. I mean whe I click on an element, this element sends to the function that save it in an array:

```
private renderTags(tag: Tags, index: number) {
    console.log('SELECTED TAG: ' + this.state.selectedTags.length);
    return <div>
        <div  onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); this.collectTags (tag); }}>
            <p 
                className={styles.tag}
                ># {tag.title} <i className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--CirclePlus"></i></p>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

I can see that elments are in fact in the selectedTags array. 
This is the collectTags function:

```
private collectTags(tag: Tags): any {
    this.setState({ savingSettings: true, tagActive: true });

    let selectedTags: Tags[] = this.state.selectedTags;

    selectedTags.push(tag);
    this.setState({
        selectedTags: selectedTags
    });


    return selectedTags;

}
```

No, I have another function that update the state of an array containing the selected elemenents. The problem is that I can't find the way to pass the array to this function:

```
private saveSettings(newTag: Tags): void {
    this.setState({ savingSettings: true, tagActive: true });

    let tags: Tags[] = this.state.items;

    // Add the new tag to the tags array and update the state
    tags.push(newTag);

    this.setState({
        items: tags,
        activeTile: -1
    });

    var cacheManager = new CacheManager();
    cacheManager.set(this.cacheKey, tags);

    this.props.provider.saveSettingsData(tags).then(() => {
        this.setState({
            savingSettings: false
        });
    });
}
```

To save the array I am trying to use an onclick event that looks like this:

```
onClick={this.saveSettings(this.state.selectedTags)}
```

In VS I am getting this error:

"Argument of type 'Tags[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Tags'.
  Type 'Tags[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Tags': title, id, defaultTag"

What can I do?

Regards
Americo

Answer (score 0):

```
private saveSettings(newTag: Tags): void {

    this.setState((prevState )=>({
        savingSettings: true, 
        tagActive: true,
        items: [...prevState.items,newTag],
        activeTile: -1
    }));

    var cacheManager = new CacheManager();
    cacheManager.set(this.cacheKey, tags);

    this.props.provider.saveSettingsData(tags).then(() => {
        this.setState({
            savingSettings: false
        });
    });
}
```

and you can call click throu ES6 function

```
onClick={()=>{this.saveSettings(this.state.selectedTags)}
```

Comment: thanks! but I still getting the same error from VS. Any idea why?

Comment: But you should not manipulate state like that as you have done right now.